# how to retrieve images from internal storage?

Tags: android, android-image, android-internal-storage

my project is to retrieve the image from  storage..when  sdcard  is there it worked fine but when sd card remove it crashes.do I need to include anything in the code?.can anyone suggest what I should do?It is possible to get the Android device Internal Download Folder path?following is my code for activity please have a look

activity:

```
public class NextActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView myImage;
private int count;
private Bitmap[] thumbnails;
private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
private String[] arrPath;
private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();// list of file paths
File[] listFile;
GridView imagegrid;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_next);
    myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gridImage);
    getFromSdcard();
    imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.griddown);
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
    imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    assert navigationView != null;
    //navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener((NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener) this);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
    // getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    //getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}
public void getFromSdcard() {
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState() == null) {
        //create new file directory object
       File directory = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory()
                + "/hairImages/");
       File photoDirectory = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory()
                + "/Hair/");
        /*
         * this checks to see if there are any previous test photo files
         * if there are any photos, they are deleted for the sake of
         * memory
         */
        if (photoDirectory.exists()) {
            File[] dirFiles = photoDirectory.listFiles();
            if (dirFiles.length != 0) {
                for (int ii = 0; ii <= dirFiles.length; ii++) {
                    dirFiles[ii].delete();
                }
            }
        }
        // if no directory exists, create new directory
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdir();
        }

        // if phone DOES have sd card
    } else if (Environment.getExternalStorageState() != null) {
        // search for directory on SD card
        File file= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
if (file.isDirectory()) { listFile = file.listFiles();
Log.d("Images","ImageSize - " + listFile.length);
for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
    f.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
}
}
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish(); // close this activity and return to preview activity (if there is any)
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    super.onBackPressed();
}
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ImageAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return f.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.grid_list_down, null);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gridImage);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.get(position));
        holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        return convertView;
    }
}
class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageview;


}}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

here is my code that crashes without sdcard:

```
   public void getFromSdcard() {
  File file= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
if (file.isDirectory()) { listFile = file.listFiles();
Log.d("Images","ImageSize - " + listFile.length);
for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
    f.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
}
}

}
```

I have tried this method but failed:

```
 public void getFromSdcard() {
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState() == null) {

        File file= new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS+"/my_file.JPEG");
        if (file.isDirectory()) { listFile = file.listFiles();
            Log.d("Images","ImageSize - " + listFile.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
                f.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }


   else if (Environment.getExternalStorageState() != null){


        File file= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS+"/");
if (file.isDirectory()) { listFile = file.listFiles();
Log.d("Images","ImageSize - " + listFile.length);
for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
    f.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
}
}}
```

Comment: Could you add the crash logs as well? It'll be easier to help you that way.

Comment: see..Im using MacBook...I can't connect my real device with Mac coz I don't have connector for it..in avd it is working fine but  crashes in real device

Comment: that is the problem I can't see the error

Comment: make sure the emulator you're using runs the same version of android as your real device. Maybe that way you'll get the same crash. It might be a problem with permissions, a problem with the fact that you don't really know if the files are in an sd card or just the device's external storage, or it might be something else altogether.

Comment: `public void getFromSdcard()` Make that `public boolean getFromSdcard()` ANd if you call it and it returns false do not continue then. Further it has noting to do with a removable micro SD card.

Comment: In `getFromSdcard()` you are trying to create directories. This makes no sense aa you are trying to list what is already there. Newly created directories are empty. Further you are not checking the return value of `mkdirs()`. Please do and return if it is false.

Comment: `listFile = file.listFiles()` Check if `listFile==null` before using it.

Comment: `if (Environment.getExternalStorageState() == null)` Have you ever seen that it is null ? Please tell. If it is null there are no directories. So all code there is useless.

Comment: can you explain in code blackcaps

Comment: What should i explain?

Comment: Blackapp im using that statement for without sdcard

Comment: With or without a micro SD card in your device: it does not matter. Your code has nothing to do with such a removable card. Your code uses the so called external memory of the device. (which is IN the device. ALWAYS).

Comment: see even if I don't use that method the app anyways crashes since it has no sd card

Comment: Read all my comments and suggestions. Adapt your code (also here so we see what you did).

Comment: `even if I don't use that method the app anyways crashes since it has no sd card` ?????? Post only code that causes the crash.

Comment: Blackapp see Im using now one common method for with or without sdcard ...it crashes

Comment: see..Im using MacBook...I can't connect my real device with Mac coz I don't have connector for it..in avd it is working fine but crashes in real device ...I have this issue

Comment: You have not applied the changes i suggested. No wonder its the same.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding crash first check that sd card is their or not and before using the selected file if u check if file is exists or not than it would solve your issue and if u are using kotlin than please use **let**  which can help you to handle null pointer